# Sorting array of dictionaries by specific key

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, dictionary, swift2

I have an array of dictionary and I'm trying to sort whole array by specific key of the dictionary, for example price value according to below example. Is there any sorting function in Swift 2.0 or should I write by myself?

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 932,
  "name": "x product",
  "price": "84.00",
},
{
  "id": 173,
  "name": "z product",
  "price": "69.00",
},
{
  "id": 818,
  "name": "y product",
  "price": "155.00",
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **NSSortDescriptor**.

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "price", ascending: true)
yourArray = yourArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor])
```

**For Swift 3.0**

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "price", ascending: true)
yourArray = yourArray.sortedArray(using: [sortDescriptor]) as NSArray
```

Where `yourArray` is an `NSArray`

Comment: I updated my code as below and it worked, thanks Rajan;

Comment: let priceSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "pPrice", ascending: true)
            let sortedByPrice = (products as AnyObject).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([priceSortDescriptor])

Comment: @mehmeet43 If it works for you, please accept as a tick as I provided a generalized approach. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use **sortInPlace** method for sorting in Swift:

```
data!.sortInPlace({$1["price"] as! Int > $0["price"] as! Int})
```

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions described here will automatically discard values where `price` is not available or is not a valid `Double` value.

### Solution 1: The structured approach

**Model**

```
struct Item: Comparable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let price: Double

    init?(dict: [String:Any]) {
        guard let
            id = dict["id"] as? Int,
            name = dict["name"] as? String,
            priceString = dict["price"] as? String,
            price = Double(priceString) else {
                return nil
        }
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
}

func <(left: Item, right: Item) -> Bool {
    return left.price < right.price
}

func ==(left: Item, right: Item) -> Bool {
    return left.price == right.price
}
```

**Data**

```
var data : [[String:Any]] = [
    ["id": 932, "name": "x product", "price": "84.00"],
    ["id": 173, "name": "z product", "price": "69.00"],
    ["id": 818, "name": "y product", "price": "155.00"]
]
```

**Sorting**

```
let sortedItems = data.flatMap { Item(dict: $0) }.sort()
```

### Solution 2: The unstructured approach

```
let sortedData = data.flatMap { (dict:[String : Any]) -> (dict:[String : Any], price: Double)? in
    guard let
        priceString = dict["price"] as? String,
        price = Double(priceString) else { return nil }
    return (dict, price) }
    .sort { $0.1 < $1.1 }
    .map { $0.dict }
```